# Displaying remote PDF via PDF.JS crashes Safari on iPad

Tags: ios, asp.net, ipad, safari, pdf.js

I'm trying to use PDF.JS to display a remote PDF on my ASP.NET website.  I have a web form called "ShowPDF.aspx" which downloads the remote PDF and response.binarywrites the file bytes.  I then have an iFrame on the website that uses showpdf.aspx as the src file for my PDF.JS viewer, so in essence it looks something similar to:

```
<iframe src="http://path/to/pdfjs/viewer.html?file=http://path/to/ShowPDF.aspx"></iframe>
```

ShowPDF.aspx is meant to be my workaround needing the PDF to be a locally available file.  On IE, Chrome, and FireFox, this all works.  On my iPad (iOS 7.0.6), Safari opens the iFrame, loads the document, and after 2 seconds, crashes (as in, safari closes completely).  Dump logs show the error:

```
Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000...
```

If I take the SAME PDF, and store it in my local web project, and reference the file, it works fine, so Im thinking it has something to do with my "ShowPDF" code.  Based on the code below, can anyone think of what I can change?  Or, does anyone have any other workarounds?  CORS won't work for me, since I don't have access to change the HTTP Headers of where my files are being hosted (azure cloud storage).  Thank you.

"ShowPDF.aspx" Code (A few lines were truncated here, but ratingPDF is a reference to a bytearray of a file stored in the cloud):

```
Dim ratingPDF As CloudBlockBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("somefilename")

Dim buffer As Byte()

Using ms As New MemoryStream
    ratingPDF.DownloadToStream(ms)
    buffer = ms.ToArray
End Using

Response.ClearHeaders()
Response.Clear()

Response.AddHeader("content-length", buffer.Length.ToString())
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=somefilename")
Response.AddHeader("Expires", "0")
Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "Cache")
Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "private")

Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"

Response.BinaryWrite(buffer)

Try
    Response.End()
Catch tEx As Threading.ThreadAbortException
   'nothing
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
```

Comment: This does not look like a bug with PDF.js per se, but a bug in Safari. I suggest to write a clear bug report and submit it to Apple.

Comment: Agree, it's better to report that to the vendor of the Safari, so they can analyze the crash further and determine if it's an exploitable one. PDF.js is just an HTML/JS solution, so any web page can do the same (or worse).

Comment: Thanks @RobW and async5, appreciate the insight.  Based on other commentary on git, I had a feeling that may be the best approach, but since I was able to isolate an issue to possibly being with my code above, I thought I would take a stab. Thanks to you both for the support for PDF.JS, it's an awesome library and head and shoulders above anything else out there...

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone else encounters this issue, unfortunately at this time I decided to just not use PDF.JS on an iPad.  Instead I open the PDF in a new browser tab instead of trying to open it "inline" in my website using something similar to the following to determine if the current device is iSomething:

```
if( navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i) ) {
    window.open('myPDF.pdf');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have run into this exact same issue attempting to embed the pdfs with an html `<object>` tag.  I ended up deciding to convert my pdfs to images with imagemagick (depending on what kind of pdf you have, you might want to choose .png or .jpg) and serving mobile userAgents the images, rather than the documents.

Another option is to convert your pdfs to HTML using [pdf2htmlEX](https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX), which creates enormous files but is interesting to look into nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

In some case you need also explicit **width and height** for the `object` tag. A dynamic value like **%** cause in my mobile framework a problem